# LocalDateTime as total nanoseconds

Tags: java, scala, date, time

I'm working with `LocalDateTime` objects and would like to store these as `Long` with nano second precision.

I've tried converting between `Instant` representation but so far failing.

For example:

`localDateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).getNano`

Returns only the nano seconds segment of `localDateTime` - is there a way to return the complete value in nanoseconds?

Similar to `toEpochSecond` but rather than in seconds, nanoseconds?

Comment: If your `LocalDateTime` really denotes time in UTC, this makes sense to do. If it is in some (known or unknown) time zone, what you are trying is incorrect and prone to lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method because you can't store all instants in a `long` number of nanoseconds.

If you are happy that the range of dates you are interested in can all fit in a long as a number of nanoseconds since the epoch, you can calculate it yourself with:

```
long nanos = ( instant.getEpochSecond * 1_000_000_000L ) + instant.getNano
```

Note that this will overflow if the date is too far in the past or the future.

Comment: @Dima, because for current date the value is of the order `2^60` or `2^61`. So if you move the date a few hundred years in some direction, it will overflow the long which has only about `±2^63` range

Comment: Dates will be close to the current so this solution works well for me. Thank you @assylias

Comment: I still recommend you check for underflow and overflow. An easy way is to compare your `Instant` to `Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, Long.MIN_VALUE)` and `Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, Long.MAX_VALUE)` (they are in year 1677 and year 2262, respectively). Or if it makes more sense in your situation, validate that your dates are within some narrower interval close to the current.

Comment: @OleV.V. Or use `Math.multiplyExact(instant.getEpochSecond, 1_000_000_000)` and check for exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

## 2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775807Z = Long.MAX_VALUE of nanos

Building on the correct Answers [by Jean-Baptiste Yunès](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48077880/642706) and [by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48077865/642706) explaining that a 64-bit long integer cannot represent all `Instant` values as a count of nanoseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z…

You could use a `long`/`Long` for a count of nanoseconds to represent moments for the next two centuries, up to `2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775807Z`, if my math is correct:

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond( ( Long.MAX_VALUE / 1_000_000_000L ) , ( Long.MAX_VALUE % 1_000_000_000L ) )
```

FYI, `Long.MAX_VALUE` = 9223372036854775807.

I'm not saying it is a good idea to do so. I am simply showing the possibility to demonstrate the issues at hand.

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/pNJVdR).

```
long seconds = ( Long.MAX_VALUE / 1_000_000_000L ) ;
long fraction = ( Long.MAX_VALUE % 1_000_000_000L ) ;
long total = ( ( seconds * 1_000_000_000L ) + fraction ) ; 
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( seconds , fraction ) ;

System.out.println( "Long.MAX_VALUE: " + Long.MAX_VALUE ) ;
System.out.println( "seconds: " + seconds ) ;
System.out.println( "fraction: " + fraction ) ;
System.out.println( "total: " + total ) ;
System.out.println( "instant: " + instant ) ;
```

> Long.MAX_VALUE: 9223372036854775807
>
> seconds: 9223372036
>
> fraction: 854775807
>
> total: 9223372036854775807
>
> instant: 2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775807Z

Answer (score 1):

From java API documentation:

> **The range of an instant requires the storage of a number larger than a
>   long**. To achieve this, the class stores a long representing
>   epoch-seconds and an int representing nanosecond-of-second, which will
>   always be between 0 and 999,999,999.

Then getting total of nanos from `Instant` can't be retrieved in a single primitive type as `long`.

Comment: That is not what the OP asked, the question is how to get the number of nanos since EPOCH, which does fit in a variable of type long.

Comment: @cbaldan this clearly explain that what he wants is not possible, you need a long AND an int, if you prefer, the number of nanoseconds from EPOCH is stored in 96 bits, that what the doc says.

Comment: unless I don't quite understand the nature of the problem, I still can't agree. I converted a `Long.MAX_VALUE` to **LocalDateTime** and I think we can store nanoseconds using a **long** var until `2262-04-11T23:47:16.000000010`.

Comment: The code I wrote was not adding the remaining nanos correctly, and I can't edit my previous comment, but after I fixed that sum, I'm getting to the same value as @Basil: `2262-04-11T23:47:16.854775807`

Comment: @cbaldan ok, all of this doesn't means that there is no date for which you can't store it in even say a byte, but this can be portable, that's all. After all, if types/api/standards are made for something, it is for the purpose of portability, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get the total number of *nanoseconds* since EPOCH from a **LocalDateTime** object is:

1. Create an **Instant** object from your LocalDateTime object
2. Sum up the result of these 2 methods:

   - **getEpochSecond()** - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#getEpochSecond--)

     - Gets the number of seconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
   - **getNano()** - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#getNano--)

     - Gets the number of nanoseconds, later along the time-line, from the start of the second.

### Sample Code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Instant instant = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    long epochNanos = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(instant.getEpochSecond(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    epochNanos += instant.getNano();

    System.out.print("Total nanos since EPOCH: " + epochNanos);
}
```